# why saved rip changed by push？

Tags: assembly, linux, gdb, x86-64

I am doing a reverse homework. see the following pictures:

[image]

as can be seen from this picture, before call `push touch3`, "saved rip" is at 0x5561dca8, which is equal to the current rsp(0x5561dca8).

once called `push touch3`, the "saved rip" is at 0x5561dca0, which is also equal to new rsp(0x5561dca0).

My question is, why push instruction changed the "saved rip" address.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the assembly code pointing your query in your question?

Comment: actually, this is a lab (attack lab) from the book csapp, which can be found in cmu csapp official website. this is code for phase-3, if you are interested in this problem, you can download it and have a try.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly, this is because the program did enough `pop` previously to get `rsp` just in front the saved `rip`. Then, a simple `push` will overwrite the saved `rip`.

As you can notice on the first picture, your saved `rip` is at `0x5561dca8` and, your `rsp` as well. Therefore, a `push` operation will store the address of the `touch3` function as return address of the stack-frame.

Nothing really difficult here.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I now _think_ I have understood the question. Didn't manage by reading the question alone.

Comment: Ah ah, I mainly guessed my way out for this one. So, do not feel guilty, I have just been lucky to get it right this time! ;-)